# Secure Amazon Gateway API to only be accessable from content in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an API that's exposed to the public internet which I've created through Amazon's Gateway API service. API calls trigger a Lambda function that queries a backend database. The API that I've created is used by an S3 static webpage to fetch data.

I'd like to secure my API so that only the contents of my S3 bucket (index.html) has permission to access my API. I'd like to prevent people from being able to query my API directly and scrape the data using curl requests, etc. I've read a little bit about IAM roles, Cognito, and the Lambda permissions model, but I'm unsure how to secure my API with all these different tools.

What is the best way to secure my API so that only the content in my S3 bucket has permission to access my API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you cannot really authorize S3 to access the API because S3 does not access your API - S3 delivers html (js/css and other static assets) to the client (web browser) of the user visiting your site. Then the call to your API is made from the client.

Plus, Amazon makes mandatory for the API Gateway to be public (makes sense but you cannot have API behind a VPC for example)

I suggest you have a deep read through the [Security and Authorization of the FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/?nc1=h_ls)

What you could be doing:

- Sign requests to the the API Gateway, but it would require to have something else generating the html code to the client (S3 can not do that itself as far as I know **but I like to be wrong**)
- Amazon API Gateway can generate a client-side SSL certificate to verify the request on the back end
- put some limits (see below)

you can also read from the FAQ if you fear about abuse

> **Q: How can I address or prevent API threats or abuse?**
>
> Amazon API Gateway supports throttling settings for each method in
>   your APIs. You can set a standard rate limit and a burst rate limit
>   per second for each method in your REST APIs. Further, Amazon API
>   Gateway automatically protects your backend systems from distributed
>   denial-of-service (DDoS) attacks, whether attacked with counterfeit
>   requests (Layer 7) or SYN floods (Layer 3).

Comment: @turtle Did you get a chance to resolve this problem ? I am having similar problem and need help to secure my s3 content from public API access from my mobile app.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your setup, you can try using one or more of AWS's [condition keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-aws-condition-keys.html) in your API Gateway's [Resource Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html). For example, you could only allow requests for which the referer is your S3 static website:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [
                "execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard*}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard*}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard*}}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Great idea but this doesn't work in practice. AWS makes API Gateways public by default, so this would just allow traffic for a specific site referer when the traffic is already being allowed. The reason that this type of policy would work for a S3 bucket is because the S3 bucket is private by default, so the policy you gave would only allow the referer while all other requests would be denied by default. Unfortunately this logic doesn't transfer to API Gateway.